# Android UI freeze when calling service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

I developed online radio app. I called shoutcast radio server by service. When i call service all of the UI controls are freezed so that i used ProgressDialog but still freezed and didn't show progress dialog. I used AsyncTask but didn't work.

**HomeFragment.java**

In button onClick event, execute CallingStreamServer AsyncTask.

```
public class CallingStreamServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting Radio Station ...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait", "Connecting Radio Station ...");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), StreamService.class));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

**StreamService.java**

StreamService create mediaplayer and connect shoutcast radio server.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");     
    try {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        sharedPreEditor = prefs.edit();

        notiManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notiTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notiMsg = "Connecting ... ";

        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainActivity, 0);

        noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(notiTitle)
                .setContentText(notiMsg)    
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();

        notiManager.notify(notiID, noti);

        String url = prefs.getString("streamURL", "");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate Method : " + e.getMessage());          


    }
}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    try {

        mediaPlayer.start();
        sharedPreEditor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        sharedPreEditor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notiTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notiMsg = prefs.getString("displayStation", "") + " radio is now playing.";

        Intent _intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, _intent, 0);

        noti = new Notification.Builder(context)                
                .setContentTitle(notiTitle)
                .setContentText(notiMsg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)   
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)              
                .build();

        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        notiManager.notify(notiID, noti);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart Method : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    sharedPreEditor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
    sharedPreEditor.commit();       
    notiManager.cancel(notiID);
    stopSelf();
}
```

Comment: Do not create dialog from your AsyncTask. Create your dialog in Service itself with context. Here the problem may be you are creating dialog and then starting your service but how you make sure that your service has completed the task and it will be captured in your onPostExecute of asyncTask.

Comment: @Rakesh my main problem is UI freeze when i calling service.

Comment: Yes, I understand your problem. Create thread or asynctask from service for any heavy call. If you need customization then try and implement observer pattern with interface and call back to pass data between after heavy processing/cal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some of the trick for my problem. In service onCreate event, mediaPlayer.prepare() is freeze for UI that point was discern from @Doug Stevenson. So that i made 1 **thread** for mediaPlayer.prepare() and mediaPlayer.start() in service. I used **BroadcastReceiver** for service calling and results. :)

**HomeFragment.java**

Register BroadcastReceiver and button onClick event send to BroadcastReceiver for service call

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == butBoxOfMusic.getId()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ACTION_STREAM_RECEIVER);
        intent.putExtra("result", "start");
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}


public class StreamServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getStringExtra("result").equals("start")) {
            /// Calling service(call from onClick event)
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait", "Connecting Radio Station ...");
            getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), StreamService.class));
        }else{
            /// Streaming playing(result from service)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

**StreamService.java** 
StreamService create mediaplayer and connect shoutcast radio server.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");     
        try {
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            sharedPreEditor = prefs.edit();

            notiManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            String notiTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
            String notiMsg = "Connecting ... ";

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainActivity, 0);

            noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(notiTitle)
                    .setContentText(notiMsg)    
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .build();

            notiManager.notify(notiID, noti);

            String url = prefs.getString("streamURL", "");
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

//          mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate Method : " + e.getMessage());          


        }
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        try {

            Thread thread = new Thread("MediaPlayer" + String.valueOf(startId)){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();                        

                        sharedPreEditor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
                        sharedPreEditor.commit();

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        String notiTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                        String notiMsg = prefs.getString("displayStation", "") + " radio is now playing.";

                        Intent _intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, _intent, 0);

                        noti = new Notification.Builder(context)                
                                .setContentTitle(notiTitle)
                                .setContentText(notiMsg)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)   
                                .setContentIntent(pIntent)              
                                .build();

                        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

                        notiManager.notify(notiID, noti);

                        /// Send reslt to BroadcastReceiver /// 
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(HomeFragment.ACTION_STREAM_RECEIVER);
                        intent.putExtra("result", "Playing");
                        sendBroadcast(intent);                      

                    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStart Method : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An Android Service onCreate is always run on the main thread, so it will block other things on the main thread, such as UI and animations.  The Service class does not provide any threading by default, so if you need that, you will have to provide it yourself.

So you will need a strategy to move all your blocking work in the service onCreate off the main thread and into some other thread.  In particular, mediaPlayer.prepare() will block for an unknown amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer.prepare()` may not return immediately, and thus this would block your UI thread. Try to use `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` and implement `OnPreparedListerner` interface to receive the callback once the `MediaPlayer` is prepared.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html